# Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: redis, socket.io

I will already setup npm, socket.io, redis and redis-server... but I can't understand this error:

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.
1:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1016:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1039:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1138:14)
```

Code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8890);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {     
    console.log("client connected");
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message');

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
        console.log("new message add in queue "+ data['message'] + " channel");
        socket.emit(channel, data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

redis.createClient() tries to connect to the local machine's redis server and try on the port number 6379. For this you need to start the redis server with the following command.

```
redis-server
```